# Definition of stability for topologically indecomposable vector bundles

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, vector-bundles

Let $E$ be a complex vector bundle over some projective manifold $X$, and assume it is topologically indecomposable (i.e. does not admit any proper non-zero subbundles). Note that I am not assuming that $E$ is holomorphic at the moment.

The slope of $E$ is defined as $\mu(E) = \deg(E)/\operatorname{rank}(E)$, where we can define $\deg(E) = \int_X c_1 (E) \wedge \omega^{n-1} $, where $n$ is the dimension of $X$ and $\omega$ is its Kähler form.

Then, I learned that $E$ is stable if for any proper non-zero sub-bundle $F$ of $E$, we have $\mu (F) < \mu (E)$, and semistable if $\mu (F) \leq \mu (E)$.

> Does this definition hold vacuously true in the case of $E$ being topologically indecomposable? In other words, are all topologically indecomposable complex vector bundles stable?

Comment: You should also take subsheaves into account, see for example this related question: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3816328/261022

Comment: @JohnnyLemmon Oh, so from that discussion, topologically indecomposable bundles need not be stable or semistable? Also, this seems to clash with the definition given in Wikipedia, where they only use subbundles for the definition of stability:  http://www.mimuw.edu.pl/~jarekw/EAGER/Lukecin02.html.

Comment: Since you assumed that there are no proper (not just nonzero!) complex subbundles, stability **in your sense** vacuously holds.